# Export Principal Curvatures in Meshlab

Tags: meshlab

How can I export the principal curvature vectors in Meshlab?

I've only been able to export the discrete curvature values like Gaussian or Mean

Comment: How did you export the curvature values?

Comment: The discrete curvature is placed in the quality field and can then be exported in for example ply format

Comment: so if I export the PLY with just the 'quality' flag ticked then the 4th vertex column is the curvature?

Comment: Yes, depending on which you calculated you'll get the mean curvature or the gaussian curvature

Comment: were you able to get this done?

Comment: Eventually I just coded it myself in python. But two years have passed, so I don't know if this has been made available in the meantime.

Comment: @Miguel, it has not still been implemented, it would be really helpful, if you can guide me on how to do it, so that I will save some time, as I am new to this.

Comment: Hi Dhiraj , you can check this link. Just keep in mind that this was developed for the lab of Prof. Kysar at Columbia University, so maybe give him a notice since I don't work there anymore. https://github.com/Marriaga/KysarCodes/blob/master/MA/MeshIO.py